# Which of these advanced learner's dictionary definitions of "adversity" is reliable?

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

I looked up *adversity* in three different advanced learner's dictionaries and here are the results.

- Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5th Edition: "a situation in which you have a lot of problems that **seem to be caused by bad luck**"
- Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary 4th Edition: "a difficult or unlucky situation or event"
- Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 9th Edition: "a difficult or unpleasant situation"

Personally, I feel like the Cambridge and Oxford definitions are too vague and generic for the need for a word like *adversity* aside from more frequently occurring words such as *difficulty* or *trouble*, which can only bring about more tiresome "the-difference-between" questions. Based on the applications of the word in my textbook which are typically in the context of "being caused by bad luck" (born blind, involved in a plane crash, stuck in a snowstorm, etc.), I feel like the Longman definition should be *the* reliable one. What do you think?

Comment: The first two definitions are very close, though CALD's 'first 'or' is probably better replaced with a slash (and/or). But CALD's 'unlucky' is less hedged than Longman's 'that seem to be caused by bad luck', and may be considered unjustified by those not believing in a malevolent 'fate'.

Comment: A lot depends on what you call "bad luck".  "Adversity" does not simply involve failing to win the lottery.

Comment: Luck is not an essential element of the definition of the term even though it is often used in situations where bad fortune is part of the cause.

Comment: Yep, someone climbing Mt Everest faces adversity, even if nothing "unlucky" happens to them.

Comment: @HotLicks Failing to win the lottery doesn't seem to be "a situation in which you have a lot of problems" though. You'd simply say "Nah, maybe better luck next time".

Comment: @HotLicks I think what the definition means is that an adversity should involve **problems**/**difficulties** that you have **no control over**, hence the "bad luck" part. A mere difficulty or trouble can be caused by yourself (=something you could have managed but chose not to, e.g. didn't cram yesterday, fail the test today)

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw - Except I have a relative who spent at least $50,000 of his parents' money failing to win the lottery.

Comment: @HotLicks Except that's not caused by bad luck. Your relative just screwed himself by spending that much of his parents' money on lottery. He should have had a choice not to play the lottery.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw - It all depends on your point of view.  He had a "system" that was "guaranteed to win".

Answer (score 1):

The term refers to situations that are unfavourable or against you for different reasons which may commonly be associated to bad luck:

[Adversity](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/adversity):

> - ***When circumstances or situations work against you, you face adversity.***  Refugees from war-torn countries encounter terrible adversity.
> - Adversity, a noun which has been part of the English language for over 800 years, comes from the Latin adversus, ***literally "turned against," and figuratively "hostile or unfavorable."***
> - ***When things seem against you — circumstances or a stoke of bad luck — you are facing adversity.*** Sometimes people use a form of the phrase "turning adversity into opportunity." This refers to the ability some people or companies have to take a bad situation and make it into a successful one.

Vocabulary.com

Comment: So which is your pick?

Comment: I think all definition are correct. The phrase  "***seem to be caused by bad luck***" is an additional note which refers to a widespread belief.